# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles. Automatic signing is disabled pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I am getting this when building a cordova ios client that has not been exported for app store manually (so Xcode has not already created the necessary profiles).

cordova 7.1.0
cordova-ios 4.5.3

How do I get cordova-ios to pass the suggested option?  My build.json looks like

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "packageType": "development",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "packageType": "app-store",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*edit*

I hacked the `build.js` file and added the option `-allowProvisioningUpdates` to `getXcodeArchiveArgs` and I can then build and export successfully (after allowing keychain access).

```
function getXcodeArchiveArgs (projectName, projectPath, outputPath, exportOptionsPath) {
  return [
    '-allowProvisioningUpdates',
    '-exportArchive',
    '-archivePath', projectName + '.xcarchive',
    '-exportOptionsPlist', exportOptionsPath,
    '-exportPath', outputPath
  ];
}
```

Don't think that's the best place for the option, but suggests I am on the right track.

So question is, how to I do this via `build.json` or the command line?

Adding the option to `"buildFlag"` in `build.json` doesn't seem to work, because although the option is picked up, it doesn't appear to be passed on to the export process.

Comment: There is a bug open for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13525